# How to use angularjs forms approach in displaying error messages for input field

Tags: angularjs, forms, error-handling

[image]

Hi 
I am looking for a way to display the error message below the input field. How do i do that?

```
 <fieldset class="has-feedback form-group">  
  <div class="animated-label">
      <input type="text" name="Full Name" class="text-field"
             data-error="Error message"
             required="">
    <label>I can pay a down payment of</label>
    <sub><img src="/assets-new-site/media/Project/FAB/Common/images/svg/icn-error.svg"
        alt="error-icon"></sub>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Tried with above, but unable to achieve label and input field on the same line and the error should be tagged only to input field and not to label.
AED should be prepopulated input value.

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap

See their documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/

You can use this kind of pattern

```
<li ng-repeat="(key,value) in new_values" ng-show="new_values[key]['show']">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{'new_' + key}}"><strong>{{new_values[key]['text']}}</strong></label>
    <input placeholder="{{new_values[key]['placeholder']}}" class="{{'form-control ' + new_values[key]['valid']}}" aria-describedby="{{'new_' + key + '_help'}}" id="{{'new_' + key}}" type="text" ng-change="update_new(key)" ng-model="new_values[key]['value']" ng-disabled="new_values[key]['disabled']">
    <small id="{{'new_' + key + '_help'}}" class="form-text text-muted">{{new_values[key]['small']}}</small>
  </div>
</li>
```

I have a data structure (object) which has all my questions stored in it so that I can use the ng-repeat on a list item to show every question I want and to store its value.

The small tag will only be displayed if it has text in it (i.e. if my data structure has a value on the key's .small property). I think you could add your error message here? You could also style it red etc.

It would look like this:
[Form-control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTb1d.png)